# Shuffling a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, shuffle

Simple question, how can I shuffle a list in Prolog, so that `A1` is the shuffled list?

```
shuffle([1,1,1,2,3,4],A1),
```

I've tried a few predicates I found on the web but none of them seems to be working. Also found [this](http://www.cs.uni-potsdam.de/wv/lehre/Material/Prolog/Eclipse-Doc/bips/lib/lists/shuffle-2.html) but apparently it's not available anymore, according to SWI-Prolog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `random_permutation/2`. [It](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=random_permutation/2) is available in SWI-Prolog.

```
?- random_permutation([1,2,3],L).
L = [1, 3, 2].
```